# EF error when including foreign key ID: Multiplicity is not valid in Role

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF Code First and my database model looks the following:

```
public abstract class Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public JobResult Result { get; set; }
}

[Table("RegisterDomainJobs")]
public class RegisterDomainJob : Job
{

}    

public abstract class JobResult
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Job")]
    public int JobId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
}

[Table("GenericJobResults")]
public class GenericJobResult : JobResult
{
}
```

However when I run the *Update-Database* command I get the following error:

```
JobResult_Job_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'JobResult_Job_Source' in relationship 'JobResult_Job'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.
```

The strange thing is that this error only happens when I keep:

```
[ForeignKey("Job")]
public int JobId { get; set; }
```

In my model.

What could be the reason of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to have one to one relationship between Job and job result table then as per entity framework guidelines you need to have your JobResult class as shown below

```
public abstract class JobResult{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Job")]
public int JobId { get; set; }

[Required]
public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
```

}

Basically your Key and Foreign key should be same which is JobId

Comment: Ahh I see - that makes perfect sense.
Thank you so much!